# Difference between static data member and global variable

Tags: c++

Variations of this question might have been asked earlier as well. This question is about static data member vs global variable not static variable vs global variable.

All of us know what static data member and global variables do. How compilers link them, where they get mapped in memory layout, their default values etc. When I think about them I do not have a clear picture of the possible scenarios where we should use static data member instead of global variable.

I thought of one use case where you want to count the number of objects created for a class. You make one static data member and increase in the ctor whenever you create an new object. But at same thought, we could also do the same thing, counting of the created objects, with the global variable as well.

So, it is not clear to me till now that what are the use cases of using static data member vs global variable?

Comment: "This question is about static data member vs global variable not static variable vs global variable." - what?

Comment: In your own example, any other piece of code can modify the global variable, giving erroneous results; this means that the number of constructions could be inaccurate. A properly encapsulated static data member does not have such issues as you control its state.

Comment: The keywords: namespace and access rights.

Comment: @user2296177, Will take that. Thanks.

Comment: @KonstantinL, Figured that out. I feel there should be more to that than just namespaces and access controls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are in different scopes:

- The `static` data member can have visibility restriction `public`/`protected`/`private`.
- The global variable can be modified without restriction
- The `static` (global) variable can only be modified in file scope.